# jQuery $(window).height wrong with dynamic added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, jquery-load

I'm using jQuery to dynamically position my footer, Now the problem is the

```
$(window).height();
```

**is wrong because i include a navigation using:**

```
$('.navigation').load('includes/navigation.html');
```

After that I check to see but the $(window).height() doesn't include the height of the added item, I add the item before checking the height so that can't be the problem. I also tried $(document).ready() and $(window).load()

Here's the full code

```
$(window).load(function(){


    $('.navigation').load('includes/navigation.html');

    var docheight = $(document).height();
    var winheight = $(window).height();

    console.log('window: ' + winheight + ', document: ' + docheight);
});
```

Comment: You should set your logic in `load()` complete callback, `load()` is async

Comment: Appending a DOM element would not affect `$(window).height()`, this is correct behaviour.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ya, sorry, even then OP should use `$(document).height();`, right?!

Comment: Yep. Although he says he is. Does the problem still exist in that case OP?

Comment: You're right! using the .load callback works! If you make it an answer i'll accept it! :) thanks!

Comment: Someone downvoted my question? what's wrong with it? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `load()` complete callback to get new document's height, otherwise as `load()` is async, you would get height before new content is added to the DOM:

```
$('.navigation').load('includes/navigation.html', function(){
    var docheight = $(document).height();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behaviour.

`$(window).height()` is the height of the browser window and *will not* be affected by elements added/removed from the DOM.

`$(document).height()` is the height of the document within the DOM and *will* be affected by DOM amends.